# How to create Hover ANIMATION Button like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at this navigation:
http://beta.viewcms.info/mint/
And you can see the hover animation!

How to create the exactly same hover menu like that?

Sorry for bad English

Comment: The menu on the right hand side of the screen with the bar that comes down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little menu for you, there you have the classes, html, and jquery you need to add.

[JsFiddle menu](http://www.jsfiddle.net/YqJ7K/2/)

Edit: I did it in 5 minutes, and didn't checked it, if it presents any problem, just let me now.

Comment: wow, you are the master!! Many thanks for this! I will try to add this code to my page.

Comment: Now I want to make a selectable are life. For example when I click Contact, the select button is change to 'contact' not stay in the 'Home' menu!!

Thanks before,

Comment: If you will not postback the page, then just do a "removeClass('selected')" on the selected one, and do "addClass('selected')" on the one just clicked.

I don't have the time to do it for you, if you can't do it, read the jQuery docs on addClass and removeClass.

Greets.